# How can I make sure an object has finished initialising before using it?

Tags: objective-c, oop, initialization

Writing some Objective-C in one method, I call `+alloc`, then `-init` to set up an object.

```
object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[object useFor:whatever];
```

The next few lines of code use the newly created object. If the aforementioned `-init` takes too long, I’m sure the program won’t “wait” before starting to use the new object, will it? If not, is there a quick way to assure the `-init` is completed?

I sometimes see programmers who write something along the lines of

```
if(object = [[MyClass alloc] init]) {
    [object useFor:whatever];
}
```

Is this what I should go for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, statements in C and Objective-C functions (and methods) are executed in sequence, in the order you write them. If you write one thing before another in a function, the first one must complete execution before the next one can execute.

The compiler may reorder statements if it believes that doing so will not change the behavior of the program (which it can predict very well in situations that don't involve concurrency), but this is an optimization. The C standard treats statements as being sequential, but allows compilers to implement this any way they like as long as the behavior of the actual program is the same as if the statements had been executed in the sequence in which they were written.

All this is a long way of saying: Your `init` method will complete before the calling method can resume execution.

Comment: Thanks, that’s very helpful. I figured method calls (or message sends) behaved differently, but now I realise this is not the case.

Answer (score 9):

When you call `init` the program will not go on to the next line until the `init` method returns. By the time you've reached the second line, the init method has completed. It may not have completed successfully, but it will have completed.

The second form is a test. First the `if` statement calls the `init` method. If a valid object is returned then the test is true and then the next statement is executed. This is why you see init methods that return `self` when they are successful and `nil` when there is a problem; so that tests like these can be run to be sure that the object has been successfully initialised before continuing.

Answer (score 4):

commands are executed in sequential order and not paralell

(dude, learn some basics ;)

Comment: Heh, thanks. Though to be fair, basics literature in ObjC usually go "LOOK ITS A TEXT EDITOR WITHOUT CODE OMG" and fail the theory.